# How to count the number of each consecutive unique character of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to count the number of each consecutive unique character of a string.

```
Case exampe:
    // Function Name    : CountUniqueChar()
    // Input        : String
    // Output       : Array Object [{k: v}]
    
    // Example : 
    // Input    : “aaaasssiia”
    // output : [{“a”: 4}, {“s”: 3}, {“i”: 2}, {“a”: 1}]
```

Comment: Please add what you hve tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for loop` to iterate over each character in a string and compare with next character to keep count of consecutive unique char.

```js
const input = "aaaasssiia";
const countChar = (str) => {
  const list = [];
  let count = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === str[i + 1]) {
      count++
    } else {
      const obj = {};
      obj[str[i]] = count;
      list.push(obj);
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(countChar(input))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) with a regular expression and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const count = (s) =>
    [...s.matchAll(/(.)\1*/g)].map(([{length}, c]) => ({[c]: length}));

console.log(count('aaaasssiia'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple achieve this using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) using `/(\w)\1*/g`

[image]

```js
const str = "aaaasssiia";
const result = str.match(/(\w)\1*/g).map((s) => ({ [s[0]]: s.length }));
console.log(result);
```